# Select based on some default value for group by having

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table that contains the names of people and respective country codes.

```
----------------
 name    |  code
----------------
saket   |   IN

rohan   |   US

samules |   AR

Geeth   |   CH

Vikash  |   IN

Rahul   |   IN

Ganesh  |   US

Zorro   |   US
```

What I wanted was that, I should able to get rows group by country `code` having names starting with `sa` first, if not then `Vi` even if not then last row of the group.

When I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable GROUP BY code HAVING name like 'sa%' or name like 'vi%';
```

But its give me rows who matched with the above condition in having clause.
I want that if condition fails then give me the last row of that group, Is it possible?.
If possible, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not very efficient, but try:

```
SELECT FIRST(`name`) AS `name`, `code` FROM (
    SELECT `name`, `code` FROM `MyTable`
        WHERE `name` LIKE 'sa%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `name`, `code` FROM `MyTable`
        WHERE `name` LIKE 'vi%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST(`name`) AS `name`, `code` FROM `MyTable` GROUP BY `code`
        HAVING `name` NOT LIKE 'sa%' AND `name` NOT LIKE `vi%'
) AS `a` GROUP BY `code`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query. It returns what you need, but be aware - this query has two pitfalls:

1. Subquery is a pain on 10^6 rows
2. Field name in outer query is nonaggregated. MySQL documentation says that is is impossible to say what value will be selected for nonaggregated.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html

```
select name, country 
from 
    (
    select *, if(name like 'sa%', 0, if(name like 'vi%', 2, 3) ) as name_order
    from tmp_names 
    order by country, name_order, name desc
) as tmp_names
group by country
order by name;
```

It returns

```
+---------+---------+
|  name   | country |
+---------+---------+
| Geeth   | CH      |
| saket   | IN      |
| samules | AR      |
| Zorro   | US      |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: If the manual says that the value will be undetermined, *why* are you suggesting the feature?

Comment: MySQL returns first value any time I did similar selection. Maybe it was luck... Anyway this can help if this selection is needed once.

Comment: I believe it would be fair to specify that it was your own observation, because that behaviour is not documented = it may change in a future version.

Comment: Yes, in this reason I noticed in post about danger in point #2.